# How to make Ultranav Trackpoint always scroll?

Tags: thinkpad, scrolling, trackpoint

I want to configure the trackpoint on my ThinkPad T510 to ALWAYS scroll. I know I can do this by holding the middle button but I don't want to do that. I want it to never be used as a pointing device, simply scroll in whatever window is under the mouse. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: have you looked at the manual of the Ultranav? Check Control Panel -> Mouse -> Properties Ultranav. There are a number of different settings available there.

Comment: I did look here and didn't find what I'm looking for. But I have a vague memory of seeing such settings in a previous or different version of Ultranav software.

Comment: It was probabaly present in a previous version of the ultranav drivers as I'm having a problem that the latest drivers no longer have the option to use the middle button as middle click and not for trackpoint scrolling.